# How to get all natural numbers out of all odd numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm building a program that does something if a counter is odd, and something else if it is even.

For the odd part of the program, I get all odd natural numbers (one at a time) so $1, 3, 5, 7... $
Now I need to do a calculation that derives all natural numbers from these odd numbers.

How can I get $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ out of $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$??

How about the same for even numbers?

Comment: 1 = (3-1)/2, 2 = (5-1)/2, 3 = (7-1)/2, ...

Comment: You don't even need all the odd numbers, just keep adding $1$ and you get every natural number: $1+1 = 2$, $1+1+1 = 3$, $1+1+1+1 = 4$, ...

Comment: what do you want to do for the even case ?? what is the other thing ?

Comment: @alkabary the same thing in the even case... just derive the natural number. The awnsers provided are more then suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get $k$ from $2k-1$, add 1 and then divide by 2. For even numbers, just divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the numbers by 2 and you'd get the natural numbers.

The haskell code would be:

f :: List a -> List a

f x = map (/2) x

Comment: The OP is given odd numbers, not even ones.

Comment: perform integer division

Comment: (For those who don't know, "integer division" is like division but you ignore the fractional part of the answer. Integer-dividing $a$ by $b$ gives $\lfloor\frac ab\rfloor$.)

Comment: But your first line didn't specify that this is the integer division, and is actually not very natural, IMHO. In any case, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: When you are dividing integers by integers division means integer division. In most programming languages a/b will perform integer division of a and b if a and b are integers.

Comment: Since your code relies on integer division, the type signature should be `f :: (Integral a) => List a -> List a` instead.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it using c++.

```
int natural;
for(int i = 1;i <= 100;i++)
{
  if(i % 2 == 1) 
{
natural = i + 1;
natural = natural /2;
cout << natural << " ";
}
}
```

This will output the first 50 natural numbers.
Here is how you can do it for even numbers

```
int natural;
for(int i = 1;i <= 100;i++)
{
  if(i % 2 == 0) 
{
natural = i /2;
cout << natural << " ";
}
}
```